# How to hide correctly input-group-addon span inside input-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to dynamically show or hide an `input-group-addon` inside an input-group.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="form-control"></div>
  <span title="" class="input-group-addon" data-original-title="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/KxDUvONgbe) is an example

The problem is, that as soon as I hide the addon, the input's width isn't correct anymore.

**Is it generally not recommend to do this or am I doing something wrong?**

(I searched for a duplicate for this question, but I couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `form.form-inline` or set container width 
http://jsfiddle.net/eot1nst7/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add another form. I tried to set a container width but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Thanks for your effort and quick response. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me and I don't know why. You can try it yourself with the link I provided in the question... it's strange. Nevertheless up vote, because it will help other users surely.

Comment: Ok, as you said, it was the width of the container of the whole thing . Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

you can add the css class "container" additional to you input-group.